# How to pick last n number of distinct messages using rxjs from stream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have been working on a piece in my ReactJs app where I will log all the client errors to the server. The idea I have is as most of the time duplicate client error can come on client side, pick the latest distinct one by "error message" and then send it to server.

Below is the error message object that I will be using:

```
{
"errorMessage":
"errorDescription":
"stackTrace":
}
```

Then I created a service class to save the message in a Subject:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class ErrorHandlingService {
    #dataStreamSubject = new Subject();
    dataStream$ = this.#dataStreamSubject.asObservable();

    addData(data) {
        this.#dataStreamSubject.next(data)
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in my component I added below code:

```
const subscription = errorService.dataStream$.pipe(
      map(data => data),
      debounceTime(2000),
      distinct()
    ).subscribe({
      next: function (value) {
        console.log(value); //Send to server
      }
    });
```

If I use this code then I will get the last most single error message that was distinct and I will send to server. But while the server is processing the request there can be lets say 2 more distinct error message coming in. So now I need to get the 2 new messages coming in the stream. The above code returns me last 1 message.
Just confused how I can handle this with rxjs operators.

Comment: I'm not going to solve your issue here I'm afraid but have you considered to use sentry? https://sentry.io it'll do exactly what you're trying to achieve with a whole UI and SDK already there for you

Comment: maybe you should use distict with key selector: distinct(k=>k.errorMessage). You can leave out map(data=>data) as it changes nothing.

Comment: @bgman But that doesn't return me an array of events that are distinct that came after last call.

Comment: you wont't get an array of events, you get the messages one by one that are distinct and each triggers the send method to the server, If you want to get an array of messages to send them together to the server, you could use buffertime operator

Comment: One more thought, an observable could emit theoretically forever, so you can't have last distinct, you only  have first distinct. If you have a finite number of error, after some time no more errors will be emitted. Take a look at distinctuntilchanged, maybe it suites better